# Can you set the Location header in a chunked http response trailer?

Tags: http, web-applications

HTTP 1.1 responses can be chunked ([spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1)). At the end of the last chunk the server can send a "trailer", which contains additional headers.

The question is: can you include a `Location` header in the trailer, and will the browser react by making a redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Location header to work should be with specific response code 3xx so in a standard response you can't use it see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: As I suspected. Let's see if someone else doesn't have different experience

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work in 3xx specifically. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Julian Reschke - he meant that if the response status is not 3xx initially, the location header won't work. So If I send 200, and then a Location header as a trailer - it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

To have the Location header, the server should be responding with the 201 or one of the 3XX status codes.  It should also include content, perhaps a message in HTML explaining what happened and giving a handy hyperlink to the resource.  The content would need to be chunked and the Transfer-Encoding header should be present and have the value "chunked".

If all this were true, then the Trailer header could be added with a value of "Location", and the Location header could then trail the content.

<strike>Here's the real issue:  This seems silly and pointless.  What use case might you have where you will redirect a client to a new location, yet you don't know that location until after the content is complete?  I can't think of a reason.  But maybe you have one?  If there's not a good use case, then I don't think you should do this.</strike>

**Edit**:  I thought of a reason.  Shiflett gives an example of chunked transfer encoding where the first chunk of HTML sent to the client says, "We are completing your transaction."  Time passes while the transaction is completed.  Then the second and final chunk of HTML is sent to the client that says, "Ok, your transaction is now complete."  (HTTP Dev's Handbook p97) Combine this idea with a 201 where a new file is created.  It might be that the location of the new file is unknown until the very end of the server's processing.  Thus it would want to use chunked transfer encoding, and it would want to put the Location header in the trailers.

**Second Edit**:  Yes, you can add it because [the spec specifically forbids](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.40) only the following header fields: Transfer-Encoding, Content-Length, and Trailer.

Comment: Well, the *real* issue is that most (all?) browsers do not implement trailers.

Comment: Fair enough.  But this could be processed by a non-browser client.  Though I still don't know why you'd want to...

Comment: Ran the tests here (http://www.browserscope.org/network/test) on IE 9, FF 9, Chrome 16, and Safari 5 (on Win 7).  It asserts that none support trailers.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Probably chicken-and-egg. No web site uses it.