# How to send the browser to an error page if part of the response has been sent (chunked)

Tags: php, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, http, jsp

This is typical scenario: a page is evaluated, and there's a buffer - once the buffer is full, the part of the page that is evaluated is sent to the browser. This uses the HTTP 1.1 chunked encoding.

However, an error can occur in one of the chunks (after the first one is already sent). In that case:

- you can't redirect (send a `Location` header), because the headers and the response status were already sent
- you can't do server-side redirect (forward), because the new page will have to be rendered after the part that is already sent - it will look ugly for sure.

So what should you do in this case? I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503447/can-you-set-the-location-header-in-a-chunked-http-response-trailer) whether you can send a Location header in the chunked trailer, but this is low-level http and the abstraction of languages may not allow it, even if it is possible (and it is likely not to be supported across browsers)

Another option is to send a `<script>window.href.location="errorPage"</script>` and thus force the client to redirect, but that's ugly. Plus you have to put `</script>` to close any potential unclosed `<script>` tag in the partial page.

(I'm tagging major web languages/frameworks, because this is an universal issue)

Comment: buffer more or in other words: prepare the result or at least verify the outcome *before* sending the headers. Once you send the double \r\n you can't tamper the response any more, it's just the body left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot redirect from the server in a chunked encoding because the headers have already been sent. The only way to perform a redirect is to send a `<script>` tag from the server and perform a client side redirect. Just out of curiosity are you trying to implement a COMET server? If this is the case HTML5 WebSockets seem better way (if the browsers you are targeting support them of course) compared to the [hidden iframe technique](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/05/the-forever-frame-technique/).

Comment: Nope. It's just a regular page (jsp) that is rendering in chunks, and when an exception occurs, it is displayed partially (which is ugly)

Comment: @Bozho, but why are you using chunked encoding for a normal jsp page? You don't know the length in advance?

Comment: It's not me, it's the servlet container default. If the buffer is filled, the response is flushed. And the default buffer size is 8kb. I'll see if I can switch it off though. (I can also increase the buffer, of course)

Comment: But I'm not sure whether it's a good idea not to use chunks (it's there by default)

Comment: I encountered this before where the response is written out in chunks, inside a loop printing out the rows, one of the rows would throw an exception, a quick fix was to do an ugly try-catch where the catch would print out an error message on that row, and let the rest of the rows to be printed... .. ugly though