# I am having issue with Rest API response in chrome only. net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome, spring-restcontroller, chunked-encoding

I am using angular as frontend and Java Spring MVC in backend.

From past few days issue has started in Chrome only.
It is throwing net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 randomly

Weirdly it is throwing error in chrome browser only.

Here are the response headers.

access-control-allow-origin: *

cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 14:22:25 GMT

strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload

transfer-encoding: chunked

x-content-type-options: nosniff;

x-frame-options: DENY;

x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block;

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744379/tomcat-7-spring-rest-template-application-producing-err-invalid-chunked-encodi?rq=1

Comment: @MichaelBerry nope it doesn't as i cannot make those changes to every users browser. needed some solution which can resolve this issue with server end

Comment: @KrutarthVora Have you every figured it out? I'm having the same problem now.